# How to perform replacements in an input string, only if a RegEx pattern is matched before the string?

Tags: python, string, replace

**Example 1:**

```py
input_text = "A las 19:30 de la tarde salimos!! hay que tener cuidado porque a eso de las 19:30pm de la tarde pasan muchos autos, ademas es importante llegar alla antes de las 20 30 hs, ya que a las 21:00 pm cierran alg1s negocios, sin embargo el cine esta abierto hasta las 23:30 pm de la noche"
```

The **output** that I need is:

```py
input_text = "A las 19:30 pm salimos!! hay que tener cuidado porque a eso de las 19:30pm pasan muchos autos, ademas  es importante llegar alla antes de las 20 30 hs, ya que a las 21:00 pm cierran alg1s negocios, sin embargo el cine esta abierto hasta las 23:30 pm"
```

**Example 2:**

```py
"Tras pasar las horas de la tarde a las 19:30 de la noche salimos de la casa juntos!! es importante llegar alla antes de las 20:30 pm de la noche, ya que a las 21:00 pm de la noche cierran alg1s negocios, sin embargo el cine esta abierto hasta la 21:00 de la noche"
```

The **output** that I need is:

```py
"Tras pasar las horas de la tarde a las 19:30 pm salimos de la casa juntos!! es importante llegar alla antes de las 20:30 pm, ya que a las 21:00 pm de la noche cierran alg1s negocios, sin embargo el cine esta abierto hasta la 21:00 pm"
```

---

If it says `"en la noche"` or `"de la tarde"` after `"pm"` or `"am"` then

**XX:XX am** or **XX:XX pm** or **XX:XXam** or **XX:XXpm**, and then **"en la noche"** or **"de la tarde"**

```py
.replace("en la noche", "")
.replace("de la tarde", "")
```

If it says `"en la noche"` or `"de la tarde"` but there is no `"pm"` or `"am"` in front of it then...

**XX:XX** and then **"en la noche"** or **"de la tarde"**

```py
.replace("en la noche", "pm")
.replace("de la tarde", "pm")
```

---

The problem is that I can't know how many times I will have to replace it in the original string and how many times I won't (there might even be a case where I enter an input_string where no replacement can be done since there are no patterns to match)

In these examples only indicate the cases of `"en la noche"` and `"de la tarde"`, but other substrings that must fulfill the same function would be for example `"por la noche"`, `"por la tarde"`, `"de la noche"`, `"del atardecer"`, `"entrada la noche"`, `"entrada la tarde"`, etc...
I suppose that these are cases that I would later add to a multiple option regex, however it is important that the regex allows adding more options in case it is required in the future.

What would be a regular expression to limit replacements to only cases where these patterns occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd split the algorithm to two parts:

```py
import re

words = r"(?:en la noche|de la tarde|de la noche)"

s = "A las 19:30 de la tarde salimos!! hay que tener cuidado porque a eso de las 19:30pm de la tarde pasan muchos autos, ademas es importante llegar alla antes de las 20 30 hs, ya que a las 21:00 pm cierran alg1s negocios, sin embargo el cine esta abierto hasta las 23:30 pm de la noche"

pat1 = re.compile(rf"(\d+[\s:]+\d+)\s*{words}")
pat2 = re.compile(fr"(\d+[\s:]+\d+\s*pm)\s*{words}")

s = pat1.sub(r"\1 pm", s)
s = pat2.sub(r"\1", s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
A las 19:30 pm salimos!! hay que tener cuidado porque a eso de las 19:30pm pasan muchos autos, ademas es importante llegar alla antes de las 20 30 hs, ya que a las 21:00 pm cierran alg1s negocios, sin embargo el cine esta abierto hasta las 23:30 pm
```

---

EDIT: Combining words:

```py
import re
from itertools import product

words1 = ["tardecita", "atardecer", "tarde", "anochecer", "trasnoche", "noche"]
words2 = [
    "en la",
    "de la",
    "por la",
    "entrada la",
    "entrado la",
    "de el",
    "en el",
    "por el",
    "entrada el",
    "entrado el",
]

words = (
    "(?:" + "|".join(f"{w1} {w2}" for w1, w2 in product(words2, words1)) + ")"
)

s = "Tras pasar las horas de la tarde a las 19:30 de la noche salimos de la casa juntos!! es importante llegar alla antes de las 20:30 pm de la noche, ya que a las 21:00 pm de la noche cierran alg1s negocios, sin embargo el cine esta abierto hasta la 21:00 de la noche"

pat1 = re.compile(rf"(\d+[\s:]+\d+)\s*{words}")
pat2 = re.compile(fr"(\d+[\s:]+\d+\s*pm)\s*{words}")

s = pat1.sub(r"\1 pm", s)
s = pat2.sub(r"\1", s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
Tras pasar las horas de la tarde a las 19:30 pm salimos de la casa juntos!! es importante llegar alla antes de las 20:30 pm, ya que a las 21:00 pm cierran alg1s negocios, sin embargo el cine esta abierto hasta la 21:00 pm
```

Comment: Excuse me, you know why if I put this regex to avoid repeating, the program stops working for some cases, for example if I do this  `words = r"(?:de la |en la |por la |del |entrada la |entrado la |de el |en el |por el |entrada el |entrado el |)\s*(?:tardecita|atardecer|tarde|anochecer|trasnoche|noche)"`  I have a problem with the **example 2**, because the substring `"19:30 de la noche"` does not become in `"19:30 pm"`.

Comment: I think that by putting `"\s*"` I generate the obligation that there is at least one empty space, and when that is not given, the pattern fails, how would I make it **none or more spaces**